# What would be the best way to check whether all fields are valid?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I have fields in a Window, some with validators and all bound to properties.
The validation works as expected.

But -

I do not want to proceed when any field is invalid. What would be the best way to determine if any validation went wrong?

Comment: Depends what data model you use, but here is a interesting link http://demo.vaadin.com/book-examples-vaadin7/book#component.field.validation.basic

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways of dealing with validation in Vaadin, all supported by Vaadin (no need for custom boolean afterValidationFlag).
One possible way (preferred by me) is shown here:

```
public class CustomWindow extends Window {

    DateField customBeanFirstPropertyName = new DateField("Caption1");
    ComboBox customBeanSecondPropertyName = new ComboBox("Caption2");
    TextArea customBeanThirdPropertyName = new TextArea("Caption3");

    BeanFieldGroup<CustomBean> binder = new BeanFieldGroup<>(CustomBean.class);

    public CustomWindow(CustomBean customBean) {
        buildLayout();
        binder.buildAndBindMemberFields(this);
        binder.setItemDataSource(new BeanItem<>(customBean));

        //add validators
        customBeanFirstPropertyName.addValidator((Validator) value -> {
            if (value == null) throw new Validator.InvalidValueException("nonnull required");
        });
        customBeanThirdPropertyName.addValidator(
                new RegexpValidator(".{3,20}", "length between 3-20 required")
        );
        /*
        or have basic validators on @Entity level with e.g. javax.validation.constraints.Size
        example:
        @Size(min = 3, max = 20)
        @Column(name = "customBeanThirdPropertyName", unique = true)
        private String customBeanThirdPropertyName;
        */
    }

    void commit(Button.ClickEvent event) { //method called by "save" button
        try {
            binder.commit(); //internally calls valid() method on each field, which could throw exception
            CustomBean customBeanAfterValidation = binder.getItemDataSource().getBean(); //custom actions with validated bean from binder
            this.close();
        } catch (FieldGroup.CommitException e) {
            Map<Field<?>, Validator.InvalidValueException> invalidFields = e.getInvalidFields(); //do sth with invalid fields
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use a FieldGroup instance to bind your fields with the properties, which is the recommended way, you can write:

```
fieldGroup.isValid();
```

That checks on all field validations of the fields managed by the field group.

Answer (score 0):

Maintain a flag. Before proceeding, check if the flag is set. In the validation code, set the flag if the validation fails.

Comment: I created a factory class for Validator proxies which tracks all validatations and is able to return whether all the Validators validate. Works like this `textField.addValidator(allValid.too(new EmailValidator("Please enter a valid email address")));` and `allValid.isAllValid()`